# display radio buttons using FormHelper

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP3

I am unable to decipher the documentation on using radio buttons to create for a list of results.

There is [create radio button](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-radio-buttons).

Which I tried this way:

```
foreach ($userGroups as $group_id => $group) {
      echo $this->Form->radio("UserGroup.$group_id.id", ['value' => $group_id, 'label' => $group]);
}
```

There is [using select pickers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-pickers).

Which says all you need to do is set the type to radio. But I checked the api and it [looks like it will unset the type](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#1822).

Anyway, I tried

```
echo $this->Form->select("user_circle_id", $userGroups, ['type' => 'radio']);
```

Nothing works.

Please advise.

**UPDATE:**

```
$userGroups = [1 => 'Group 1', 2 => 'Group 2']; // basically primary key is keys and the display fields are the values.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following syntax :

```
$selectedStatus = 1;

$attributes = array('legend'=>false,'value'=>$selectedStatus,'class'=>'sortByStatusCourse','name'=>'sortByStatusCourse');
$options = array("1"=>"Active","0"=>"Inactive");
echo $this->Form->radio('is_active', $options,$attributes);
```

Code explanation :
 We are passing parameters to cakePHP core so that it will output Radio button in HTML.

```
echo $this->Form->radio :
```

Here 1st param is Name on field in Database. 2nd param is What are the options for radio buttons , its value and text .3rd param is what are its attributes like what should be its default `value` here I explicitely set it to `1` so it will already tick radio with `Active`text.

According to your code : `echo $this->Form->radio("UserGroup.$group_id.id", ['value' => $group_id, 'label' => $group]);`

I think order of param is wrong as you pass `VALUE` in 2nd param which should be 3rd param.Check my code.

Comment: Thanks your answer helped. The correct code is `echo $this->Form->radio("user_circle_id", $userGroups);`

Comment: @KimStacks , welcome , and please edit question and write -> `update : ` and write what you used for  `$userGroups` , I mean that array as it does not appear in your question.